# Using "do" in Scheme

Tags: scheme, do-loops

What is the difference between CODE SNIPPET 1 and CODE SNIPPET 2?

```
;CODE SNIPPET 1
(define i 0)                      
(do ()                             
  ((= i 5))                       ; Two sets of parentheses
  (display i)                     
  (set! i (+ i 1))) 


;CODE SNIPPET 2
(define i 0)                      
(do ()                             
  (= i 5)                         ; One set of parentheses
  (display i)                     
  (set! i (+ i 1)))
```

The first code snippet produces 01234 and the second produces 5. What is going on? What does the extra set of parentheses do? Also, I have seen `[(= i 50)]` used instead of `((= i 5))`. Is there a distinction? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "produces"? The first snippet *prints* "01234" and *evaluates* to nothing. The second snippet doesn't *print* anything, and *evaluates* to 5.

Answer (score 17):

The general structure of a do form is like this:

```
(do ((<variable1> <init1> <step1>)
     ...)
    (<test> <expression> ...)
  <command> ...)
```

Paraphrasing http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-6.html#node_chap_5, each iteration begins by evaluating `<test>`, if it evaluates to a true value, `<expression>`s are evaluated from left to right and the last value is returned as the result of the `do` form. In your second example `=` would be evaluated as a boolean meaning true, then i would be evaluated and at last 5 is the return value of the form. In the first case `(= i 5)` is the test and the `do` form returns an undefined value. The usual way to write a loop would be more like this:

```
(do ((i 0 (+ i 1)))
    ((= i 5) i)      ; maybe return the last value of the iteration
  (display i))
```

You don't need an explicit mutation of the loop variable as this is handled by the `<step>` expression.

Answer (score 6):

In the first case, *((= i 5))* functions as a test for termination. So the do loop is repeated until i = 5.

In the second case, (= i 5) isn't a test. The do loop simply executes the first form, which returns *5*.

--

(Per the attached comments) brackets are interchangeable in some dialects of scheme. It is sometimes considered idiomatic to use [] for parameters (i.e. to the parent *do*).

Comment: Some dialects of Scheme allow `[]` as well as `()` to mean the same thing. The distinction is just to enhance the visual difference between the groups.

Comment: In particular, the very popular Racket/mzscheme dialect allows any set of paired brackets to be used interchangeably, so for example `{= [+ 1 2] (- 7 4)}` returns `#t`. The imbalance was surely a typo. I've noticed a tendency to use square brackets for special "syntactic" lists like the one in question.

Comment: Harman: I see the imbalance was corrected in the original question before I read it. I assume that was just a typo.

Comment: @newacct You are correct; for some reason I mentally parsed = as an assignment operator, and the do evaluating all forms rather than just the first one. Have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: um, no. the `do` loop does not "simply execute" the second form. What does that even mean??